# How to best experience your finished architectural model w/o diving into a game-engine

Tags: game-engine, texture-baking

(Bear with me please, I am re-entering the world of CGI after many years, and I never made it past the "hobbyist" level anyways.)

I love I can Navigation->Walk in Blender, but it has two obvious limitations: no collisions, and it looks meh.

1. Is there an easy way of curing those without transforming your model into a game level, i.e. creating a game? It sounds like something that would have a one-click solution.
2. Also I wonder if one could pre-render the textures somehow so the result looks **better** than an AAA-game? Not sure this is what texture-baking means, but the idea is that if the textures got lit and cast shadows on by a dedicated non-real-time render engine (e.g. Cycles), so one would not have to leave them for the real-time game engine to ruin... And maybe it could look better?
   Obviously the real-time engine would need to **NOT apply** lighting on these textures, as they would be already lit from the dedicated renderer. Such engine would also need to deal with some kind of simplified refraction. (Not sure any useful data can be pre-calculated for that.)

You would make several renders of your scene, so Cycles can take a look all the faces you care for, then all the rendered faces would get exported with their pixel data, and the result would get loaded into some sort of viewer...? I presume even a crappy GPU could handle that, as long as it could fit the textures into memory.

I found [one question on that topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161345/i-need-to-be-able-to-walk-someone-through-a-3d-model-in-real-time), but the answers point either to a DIY solution involving a game engine, or recommend to use Evee which is nowhere near what I think should be possible. (Seems like that's what Material Preview mode does.)
Also I tried to google "real-time v-ray" for example, but found nothing even remotely promising.
Possibly viz4d.com might be aiming at doing that, but that's a Max-specific solution.

P.S.: I would have added a "real-time" tag but I don't have the rep needed.

Comment: here's an old video from Andrew Price, hopefully still relevant - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html